# thread in a webapplication (servlet, Spring , hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I understood the basic concept of Thread in standalone application. But, got confused in below areas.

1). In Java webapplication (servlet and Spring based)?

I hope, each request is handled by a different thread. Is this correct? Is there any other definition available?

2). what is a thread in Hibernate with Spring MVC?
Session factory is thread safe.. where as session object is not. What is mean by thread here?

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The application server has a thread pool, when a request comes in it gets assigned a thread from the pool.The same thread calls the dispatcher servlet, which calls a controller, which calls a service, etc., and finally creates an HttpResponse and sends it to the client.

2) A usual pattern with Hibernate (if you're not using Seam conversations) is [session-per-request](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request):

> 2.4.2. Session-per-request pattern
>
> This is the most common transaction pattern. The term request here
>   relates to the concept of a system that reacts to a series of requests
>   from a client/user. Web applications are a prime example of this type
>   of system, though certainly not the only one. At the beginning of
>   handling such a request, the application opens a Hibernate Session,
>   starts a transaction, performs all data related work, ends the
>   transaction and closes the Session. The crux of the pattern is the
>   one-to-one relationship between the transaction and the Session.

The transaction is stored by Spring in a threadlocal variable. So the thread has a Hibernate session (which is confined to that thread), and it is associated with a transaction (or a stack of transactions, since they can be nested).

Comment: hi Nathan Hughes,can you pls advise me few reference books to get more idea on this?

Comment: @SR: most reference books are at a beginner level. for any kind of depth it's better to go to the online doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html